# How can I screen share and use Pages?

Tags: remote-desktop, pages, screen-sharing

Via Remote Management (VNC) I am connecting to a **virtual** display on a Mac running Lion. VNC is working as expected, except Pages '09 documents show up blank. If, however VNC connects to the Mac and controls the **physical** display then Pages documents show up as expected.

Is it possible to use Pages using a virtual display over VNC?

VNC Clients that I've tested are: TightVNC & RealVNC running on Windows, or Apple's Screen Sharing app on Lion.

Comment: What sort of computer are you VNCing from and what app are you using to do so? What version of OS X is running on the Mac that is running Pages? What version of Pages is it?

Comment: Clarifications added. The behavior seems like Pages is limiting it's use to the physical display only.

Comment: What do you mean by a "virtual display"? I've used Pages over VNC before, but only with the laptop open and Pages on the physical display.

Comment: "Virtual display" is new in Lion, it allows a remote user to login into a separate session and not take over the local user's physical display. This page from Apple in the section named "Lion Screen Sharing" provides some information http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4715

Comment: Huh. Cool feature I'd never heard of. It sounds like a bug in Pages's rendering. Does any other app do that, too, particularly Keynote or Numbers?

Answer (score 4):

Excuse the large picture, but I have used Screen Sharing to share the screen of an iMac running Lion and Pages '09 over the virtual display, and it works just fine.  I suspect that the assumed problem of with pages inability to work over a virtual VNC connection is not accurate, but there is something more local to your machine that needs attention.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I have tried using several of our Mac's in the office. We are running iWork that was purchased from physical media instead of the app store. Other than changing that I can't think of any configuration changes. How are you establishing the connection, simply Finder Share screen?

Comment: Exactly that.  Also using CD versions of iWork.  Computers, eh!?